# NSPredicate omits special characters like á â á in filterContentForSearchText method

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I am developing an app with an **UISearchBar** and I need to filter some names with special characters like **à, è, ê** and so on.. but if I don't type the correct string with the special character it doesn't appear.

Ex: If I am looking for **cómodo**  word I can't find this word if I don't type exactly **có**

How could I get that word without type that special characters? for example typing just **co**.

This is my `NSPredicate`:

```
 NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.word BEGINSWITH[c] %@",
                                    searchText];
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you got the solution for above one ? If you got it, put your solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore diacrtical needs to be specified, "[cd]" instead of "[c]".

See NSHipster: [NSPredicate](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/).

`NSComparisonPredicate` Options:
`NSDiacriticInsensitivePredicateOption`: A diacritic-insensitive predicate. You represent this option in a predicate format string using a [d] following a string operation (for example, "naïve" like[d] "naive").

Such a common error, it kept me from finding my Metro Station in Paris.